# How to take the backup of a dataset in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, backup

We want to create a backup copy of a BigQuery dataset in case a table is accidentally dropped, as it is only recoverable [within 7 days](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable).

Is there a way to extend the duration of the recovery period? If not, how can we create a backup of a dataset with a retention period of 30 days in BigQuery?

Comment: I should note that the Cloud BigQuery product team already aware of your interest on this feature request and I recommend to star [this ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/120038872) to follow your feature request.

Comment: Edited to highlight that this period has been extended to 7 days since original question was posted.

Comment: Also worth noting that feature request was marked as "won't fix"

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible to extend the duration of the recovery period. A feature request for the ability to extend the duration of the recovery period has already been created as commented by Katayoon.

Here is a public link to monitor the progress on that issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/120038872

To backup datasets in BigQuery you could either make copies of your dataset, or as a more workable solution, export the data to Cloud Storage, so you can import it back at a later time. Cloud Storage allows you to set a retention period and a lifecycle policy which together will allow you to make sure that data stays undisturbed for the desired amount of time, and that it removes itself after a given time should you wish to save on storage costs.

For how you do export in BigQuery:
You can export the tables as AVRO, JSON or CSV files to the Cloud Storage via web UI, command line, an API and using various languages like C#, Go, Python and Java, as long as both are in the same location. There are other limitations to exporting a table, such as file size, Integer encoding, data compression, etc.
Link to table export and limitations:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

You can find the instructions on the procedures here:
Retention Policies and Bucket Lock: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-lock#lock-bucket
Object Lifecycle Management:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles

Loading data into BigQuery can be done using various file formats, such as CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet, or ORC and so on. At this moment you can load directly only from local storage, or from Google Storage. More on loading data, file formats, data sources and limitations by following the link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data

More information on 
Exporting tables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data
Export limitations: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations 
Loading data into BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data 
Wildcards: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames
Merging the file: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose

Answer (score 2):

You can take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-create#sql) of a table using either SQL or CLI:

SQL

```
CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE
  myproject.library_backup.books
  CLONE myproject.library.books
  OPTIONS(expiration_timestamp = TIMESTAMP "2022-04-27 12:30:00.00-08:00")
```

CLI

```
bq cp --snapshot --no_clobber --expiration=86400 library.books library_backup.books
```

Answer (score 0):

You can backup and restore using the tools in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-oreilly-book/tree/master/blogs/bigquery_backup:

Backup a table to GCS

```
./bq_backup.py --input dataset.tablename --output gs://BUCKET/backup
```

This saves a schema.json, a tabledef.json, and extracted data in AVRO format to GCS.

You can also backup all the tables in a data set:

```
./bq_backup.py --input dataset --output gs://BUCKET/backup
```

Restore tables one-by-one by specifying a destination data set

```
./bq_restore.py --input gs://BUCKET/backup/fromdataset/fromtable --output destdataset
```

For views, the backup stores the view definition and the restore creates a view.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to extend the duration of the recovery period in BigQuery by using the time-travel function. It's just 7 days.

However, Google BigQuery now supports snapshots, which are much more powerful than the time-travel feature because they let you keep BigQuery backups for as long as you need them.

Snapshots preserve the content of a table at a chosen time. It can be the content fetched at the time of creating a snapshot or any timestamp from the previous seven days.

What’s more, snapshots can but don’t need to have an expiry date, at which point they’ll be deleted from the system. For example, you can choose to take daily snapshots of your tables but keep each snapshot only for a month.

There are also alternative ways to [back up BigQuery](https://blog.coupler.io/bigquery-backup/). For example, you can export your dataset to Google Cloud Storage. You can use the BigQuery Export feature to export your dataset to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). This will create a copy of your dataset in GCS, which you can use to restore your data if it is accidentally deleted. You can set the retention period for your GCS bucket to 30 days or longer if you want to keep your backups for a longer period.

Also, there are several third-party backup tools available that can help you create backups of your BigQuery dataset. These tools typically allow you to schedule regular backups and store them in a location of your choice, such as Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, or your own on-premises storage.